# D3 map transition fail

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, transition, topojson

I using D3 to transition one India map (India.json) to its cartogram (India_simple.json).Both of these are in topojson format. My final goals is to achieve a transition like the one shown in this demonstration by Max Galka - http://metrocosm.com/how-to-make-cartograms-with-animation/ . In particular Im referring to the US map transition demo - view-source:http://metrocosm.com/shape-transition.html

But unfortunately the transition function is not working. The code is as follows -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Set a style for our worldshape-data -->
  <style>
  path {
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    fill: grey;
  }
  </style>
<body>

  <!-- implementation of the hosted D3- and TopoJson js-libraries -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>

  <!-- map creation --> 
  <script>
  // canvas resolution
  var width = 1000,
      height = 600;

  // projection-settings for mercator    
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
      // where to center the map in degrees
      .center([100, 30 ])
      // zoomlevel
      .scale(700)
      // map-rotation
      .rotate([0,0]);

  // defines "svg" as data type and "make canvas" command
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // defines "path" as return of geographic features
  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  // group the svg layers 
  var g = svg.append("g");

  // load data and display the map on the canvas with country geometries
  d3.json("india.json", function(error, topology) {
    d3.json("india_simple.json", function(error2, topology2) {
      var map = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.collection)
            .geometries)
      .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path);



        setInterval(function(){                   
  map
    .data(topojson.object(topology2, topology2.objects.collection))
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .attr("d", path);

    setTimeout(function(){
      map
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.collection))
        .transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("d", path);


    }, 3000)
}, 6000);      
  });
        });




  // zoom and pan functionality
 /* var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .on("zoom",function() {
          g.attr("transform","translate("+ 
              d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
          g.selectAll("path")  
              .attr("d", path.projection(projection)); 
    });

  svg.call(zoom)*/

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The observed output is only the india_simple.json map. 
The setInterval and setTimeout functions are not working. I cant see any error in the console either.

The india.json and india_simple.json files are placed in dropbox - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wrxyngyq4jdie9c/AACG2-dTzC79rRvlxlOC5poBa?dl=0
Please help me obtain the required transition

Comment: where is India_simple.json? Your DBox has India and the Word.

Comment: @Klaujesi - You can see it now in the same link